# CSS - Scrollbar is not visible when scrolling with mouse wheel

Tags: html, css, scroll, scrollbar

I am making a scrollable component, and although it properly scrolls, the actual scrollbar does not show up when I scroll using the mouse wheel or arrow keys. The scrollbar only shows up when I hover along the side of the component, where you expect the scrollbar to be.

How can I make it so that when I scroll using the mouse wheel/arrow keys, the scrollbar shows up? I have tried setting `overflow-y` in my component to `auto` and `scroll`, but both yield the same result.

Here is the css for this component:

```
.component {
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

I am using Chrome and MacOS

Answer (score 0):

In some browsers, the default behavior is to hide the scrollbar until the user interacts with the scrollable element. You can use the `::-webkit-scrollbar` pseudo-element to force the scrollbar to always be visible:

```
.component {
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

/* Force scrollbar to always be visible */
.component::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
}

.component::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

.component::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #888;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.component::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #555;
}
```

Comment: I don't want to force the scrollbar to be always visible. I want it to be visible only when I scroll using the mouse wheel/arrow keys.